# how to query navigation properties code-first MVC4

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first

What is wrong here? I have a many to many between products and transactions. Trying to build the `view` but I can't get any intellisense for the query to load the `ProductTransaction` table.

entity 1

```
     [Table("Transactions")]
public class Transaction
{
        [Key]
        public virtual int TID { get; set; }

        public virtual int FromUserID { get; set; }
        public virtual int ToUserId { get; set; }
        public virtual int itemForId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
```

entity 2

```
      [Table("Products")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage="Name can't be longer than 50 characters bitch")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? UploadDate { get; set; }

    public virtual byte[] ProductImage { get; set; }
    [StringLength(25)]
    public virtual string MimeType { get; set; }

    public virtual int Views { get; set; }

    public virtual int Qty { get; set; }

    // Relations
    public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bag> Bags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions{ get; set; }
}
```

controller method to see all transactions and trades: query has no intellisense for `Products`

```
     public ViewResult GetTrades()
    {
        //Include is not recognizing any nav properties

        var friend = db.Transactions.Include(a => a.Products);

    }
```

many to many relationship

```
       modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Products)
            .WithMany(t => t.Transactions)
            .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("ProductTransactions");
                    m.MapLeftKey("ProductId");
                    m.MapRightKey("TID");


                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DbExtensions.Include(this IQueryable, Expression<Func<T, TProp>>)` is an extension method.

You need to include the namespace to access it as an extension method.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: quick and painless. Thanks Aron. I may have another question about displaying the nav properties in the view. If so, hopefully you can help.